# Upload a TSV file into Google Drive via the API and remove qualifying quotes around each cell

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm trying to upload TSV file to Google Drive and have its contents converted to a spreadsheet by using the ?convert=true flag when sending the file. Everything seems to be working well, except when the file is converted none of the quotes are being removed from around each cell of data. The result looks like this:

[image]

I have the same problem when uploading via the UI in Google Docs, unless manually set the "Separator character" to be "Tab". In the UI, this fixes the problem and the quotes are automatically removed from the import.

My question is: can I manually specify a separator character when importing a file into Google Drive via the API? Or can I format my file in some way that specifying a separator character is not necessary? I have to keep the quotes in place because some of my content contains new line characters. Without the quotes the importer can't tell that the content is part of the same cell.

I'm already transferring the file with the mimeType set to "text/tab-separated-values". I've also tried formatting with commas and uploading as a "text/csv", but that had even worse results with all the cells jammed into the first column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drive API doesnt support a custom separator character. We're not keeping the feature parity between the UI and the API in this case, we're considering it as an enhancement.

Comment: Hi, thanks the response Burcu! What about alternatives? Is there any way to get a CSV/TSV into Google Drive that maintains new line characters properly? As of right now I'm left only with stripping out newlines and tab characters in the data and replacing them with spaces.

Comment: I marked this accepted, but it seems like there's no way to do what I've requested: import data that contains new lines. Doh. Here's hoping the API gets this ability eventually.

Comment: I made an internal feature request to provide a separator param, fyi.